# How to prevent from calling function multiple times in recompose?

Tags: android

There is a code like below

```
@Composable
fun PersonComposable(person: Person) {
  Text(text = person.fullName())
}

data class Person(val firstName, val secondName) {
  fun fullName() {
    return "$firstName $secondName"
  }
}
```

in this case when PersonComposable recompose, fullName function called.
(for example, this screen has scroll, fullName function will be called multiple times when the screen is scrolled)

If fullName has complicated calculation which takes a while, this code has bad performance.
When we use fragment, we don't need to worry about this because in fragment fullName only called once.

It feels like we have this fullName function in onDraw, onLayout in View.
How to prevent this fullName function from called multiple times?
I want this function called only once like we use this in fragment + viewModel

I tried use mutableStateOf but I don't think this is the right way because it's nonsense to make all fields in mutableStateOf.

Comment: Try using `val fullName = remember(person) { person.fullName() } `.